# Can I use methods in multi-line strings ? [Invalid Syntax]

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know why my code is accusing invalid syntax. If I remove the f in the beginning of quotation marks, the code runs

```
output = f'''
---------VAREJAO_CIN---------------
nome : {sp_1.getNome()}
cnpj : {sp_1.getCNPJ()}
endereco: {sp_1.getEndereco()}
saldo : {sp_1.getSaldo()}
-----------------------------------

-----------COMPRA_UFPE-------------
nome : {sp_2.getNome()}
cnpj : {sp_2.getCNPJ()}
endereco: {sp_2.getEndereco()}
saldo : {sp_2.getSaldo()}
-----------------------------------

--------ESTUDANTES_VARZEA----------
nome : {sp_3.getNome()}
cnpj : {sp_3.getCNPJ()}
endereco: {sp_3.getEndereco()}
saldo : {sp_3.getSaldo()}
-----------------------------------
'''
```

^^^ it appoints invalid syntax here

Comment: Could you post the actual error message?

Comment: So-called f-strings have been introduced in Python 3.6, are you using an older version?